# gt table conditional format using values from multiple columns

Tags: r, formatting, gt

The gt package is pretty new but wanted to see if there's a way to conditionally format based on the contents of multiple columns.

gt's default appears to only conditionally format by column.

So in this example both columns are colored identically despite column y being significantly larger.

```
library(gt)

data.frame(
  x = 1:10, 
  y = 101:110) %>% 
  gt() %>% 

data_color(
  columns = c("x", "y"),
  colors = scales::col_numeric(
    palette = c("#d67f90", "white", "#689d7c"),
    domain = NULL
  )
)
```

[image]

Is it possible to use all the data to conditionally format; in this way the gt table would probably look like this (via good ole' Excel).
[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the `domain` parameter of `scales::col_numeric()`:

```
library(gt)

df <- data.frame(
  x = 1:10, 
  y = 101:110) 
  
gt(df) %>% 
data_color(
  columns = c("x", "y"),
  colors = scales::col_numeric(
    palette = c("#d67f90", "white", "#689d7c"),
    domain = range(c(df$x, df$y))
  )
)
```

[image]